# Сегментирование

Tags: ассемблер

Пусть переменная E описана в сегменте E1

```
CODE SEGMENT  
ASSUME DS:D1,ES:E1,SS:S1  
;DS=1000H,ES=2000H,SS=3000H  
;BX=1000H,BP=2000H,SI=0F00H  
MOV AX,E[BP]
```

Нужно определить вставит ли ассемблер в объектный код префикс замены сегмента.
Я считаю,что вставит сегмент SS,но в ответах написано ES.Кто-нибудь может помочь разобраться

Comment: То есть собрать и посмотреть уже лень? Тем более что ответ на вопрос более чем зависит от конкретного ассемблера. В тех, что использую я, например, директивы `ASSUME` вообще нет...

Comment: 16-разрядный ассемблер

Comment: Вижу, что не 8-разрядный. masm, tasm, nasm, yasm, goasm, fasm, gas - ... - какой именно? Впрочем, вопрос в любом случае имеет простой ответ: соберите своим ассемблером и проверьте.

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!! Вы прям очень помогли!

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. явно указано, что переменная находится в сегменте `E1`, адрес которого записан в `ES`, то естественно, что компилятор должен будет явно указать, что адрес должен считаться относительно `ES` (добавив соответствующий префикс сегмента), иначе по-умолчанию будет использоваться сегмент `SS` (если в качестве базового регистра использован `SP` или `BP`) или `DS` (в остальных случаях).

Answer (score 0):

1. Не бывает ассемблера "вообще". Как не бывает, например, компилятора C "вообще". Есть конкретные реализации компиляторов, и есть конкретные реализации ассемблеров. Например, TASM, MASM, NASM, WASM, GAS, fasm, Yasm, GoAsm и т.д.
2. Директива `ASSUME` прямого отношения к языку ассемблера не имеет. Это дополнительная конструкция, используемая некоторыми реализациями ассемблеров. Поэтому никакого стандартного поведения у неё нет (особенно, понятное дело, в тех ассемблерах, где она вообще не поддерживается...). И смотреть на её работу нужно в документации по конкретной реализации ассемблера. Не удивлюсь даже, если пример будет работать то с SS, то с ES, в зависимости от реализации :)

Вывод: лучший критерий - практика. Собрал нужным ассемблером, посмотрел что получилось, взял с полки пирожок и пошёл гулять :) Ибо весь процесс собрал/посмотрел занимает куда меньше времени, чем теоретизирование и ожидание ответа где-то в тырнетах...